# Is it possible to create(deploy) HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) on Android(4.x)?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to invoke(deploy) HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) on Android(4.x)?
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Obviously iOS devices can both capture/play, and I know android can at least play, but how about capturing? I wonder interoperability.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found so far is

Creating a HLS video stream with FFmpeg
12 May 2013

http://walterebert.com/blog/creating-on-hls-video-stream-with-ffmpeg/

```
For video conversion I use FFmpeg. Creation of HLS is possible with FFmpeg, but not really well documented. So I had to figure out how to create the video streams. After a lot of research and experimentation I created my FFmpeg HLS reference implementation that is available on Bitbucket.

On iOS the created video plays without problems on new devices. Older iOS devices with a maximum resolution of 480×320 pixels seem to select the best quality stream available, even if they cannot play it. For Android you have to create a MP4 video and before converting it into a MPEG stream. Doing this in a single command creates a choppy stream on Android. Flash playback has still some issues if you change the bitrate. So I still have some work to do.

These are the writings of Walter Ebert on web development, web design and free, open source software
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. HLS is widely used on Android 4.x.